# Cómo insertar registros que no están en otra tabla?

Tags: base-de-datos

Saludo, tengo dos tablas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero insertar un nuevo registro en la segunda tabla siempre y cuando el ddp_coddcp no exista en el dcp_codigo de la primera tabla.

Es decir; que me vaya comparado. Por ejemplo el 178 ya existe en la segunda tabla, entonces no inserte, el 182 ya existe entonces no inserte, el 186 no existe entonces ese sí que se inserte.

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Saludos. No me queda claro el obstáculo que tiene (mensaje de error, lo que ocurre en vez de lo que espera), así mismo el código que usa para realizar la inserción del nuevo registro. Recuerde que si hay `CONSTRAINT` habilitado al respecto no podrá.

Comment: Eso se puede resolver con un trigger before insert sobre la segunda tabla. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Las respuestas pueden variar dependiendo de qué motor de BD uses (y no lo indicas en la pregunta). Edítala y añade esta información. Como sugerencia para próximas oportunidades, esta misma información, junto con las sentencias DDL de las tablas (los `create table`) pueden ponerse como texto, no como imagen. Así otros podrán ayudarte más fácil creando un sqlfiddle en vez de transcribir a mano los elementos de tu pregunta. A ver qué pasa si alguien te pone la respuesta como una imagen...